# Enabling save a template on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

We need to save a list on sharepoint online but the option that enables save as a template is not visible..

Answer (score 1):

what type of site is it?

by default sharepoint online disables custom scripts on a given site collection:

to enable:

goto central admin -> sharepoint -> settings -> select "Allow users to run custom script on personal sites and self-service created sites"

[image]

from msdn:

> Allowing custom script is a way to let users change the look, feel,
>   and behavior of sites and pages to meet organizational objectives or
>   individual needs. If you allow custom script, all users who have "Add
>   and Customize Pages" permission to a site or page can add any script
>   they want. (By default, users who create sites are site owners and
>   therefore have this permission. For more info about SharePoint
>   permission levels, see Understanding permission levels in SharePoint.)

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Allow-or-prevent-custom-script-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f

you could do it in sharepoint designer. go to the list and top menu to the right is the option to save the list as template.

within the browser:

list settings -> in the "Permissions and Management column" click "Save list as template"

Comment: Its a sub-site to a team site...

Comment: have you allowed custom script?

Comment: updated my answer. you need to enable custom script first to show save list as template

Comment: did it but still not working..

Comment: what type of site is it?

Comment: can you go to the list/library settings. in the url take a note of the guid. now go to this url /_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx?List= and paste in the guid. does it take you to the page or does it display an error?

Comment: just as a note it takes time for the settings to take effect! (turning scripting on) so wouldnt see the change till the next day possibly!

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable "**Allow users to run custom script on personal sites** " and "**Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites**" .
2. Check if **Community Sites Feature** site feature, the **SharePoint Server Publishing** site feature, or the **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** site collection feature is currently enabled or was previously enabled for the affected site.
3. Check if the account have **full permission** to access the site and list .

Also the workaround like Ali mentioned , replace the URL from **.../listedit.aspx?List={GUID}** to **../savetmpl.aspx?List={GUID}** , now you will be able to save the library as a template .